# Show dropdown value in Laravel Blade file

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have a drop-down with three predefined values. Now, I want to pass the selected value to another Blade file. The problem is I can show it on the same page, but I want to display the selected one on the content.blade.php page. Ajax/jQuery doesn't accept. If you have any solution without using Ajax or jQuery, please help. I tried with JavaScript and jQuery but did not find a solution. If someone has an easy solution with Laravel, I would appreciate it.

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-6">                             
  <select name="xyz" id="xyz" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="xyz1">xyz1</option>
    <option value="xyz2">xyz2</option>
    <option value="xyx3">xyx3</option>
  </select>
  <p id="demo"></p> 
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("xyz").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: _"but I want to display the selected one on the content.blade.php page"_ - either make this a proper form that targets whatever URL is necessary to invoke the controller that would display `content.blade.php`(and receive your form parameters in that controller, so they can be passed on to the template) - or, if you do not want to go _directly_ to that second page, but only show the selected value there some time latter: Store it into the session.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a Laravel problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the name of route opening your file 'content.blade.php':

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("xyz").value;

  var url = "{{ route('route.name', ':value') }}";
  url = url.replace(':value',x)
  location.href= url;
}
```

on the web route file :

```
Route::get('/url/{value}, [ControllerName::class, 'yourFunction']->name('route.name');
```

on the controller file :

```
public function myFunction($value){
 return view('content', compact('value'));
```

}

and on your content file you display the value variable